# svg rectangle border not drawing properly

Tags: html, css, svg

Just getting started using `<svg>`s.

I am trying to draw a simple rectangle with a border, but it seems like the border is somehow giving me a shadow-like effect. It seems to draw the right and bottom border much thicker than the top and left border. Very weird.

This happens when I do rounded edges and when with normal sharp edges.

Here is the code:

```html
<svg>
    <rect width="30" height="30" rx="5"
      style="fill:rgb(255,255,255);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"/>
</svg>
```

I've included a PLNKR: http://plnkr.co/edit/HGBTNyjasqzwtguOIbnV

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your rectangle is being clipped by the edge of the `<svg>`. The stroke width makes the rect wider but doesn't automatically adjust its position. Add `x="1"` and `y="1"` to your `<rect>`

```html
<svg>
    <rect x="1" y="1" width="30" height="30" rx="5"
            style="fill:rgb(255,255,255);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Matthew is right. Another solution could be modify SVG's default value for the property `overflow: hidden` to `overflow:visible`.